# How to access objects in other class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to access a function in ViewController 1 from ViewController 2. This works (confirmed by breakpoints and NSLog output). But accessing an object which is defined in ViewController 1 is **nil** when called from ViewController 2.

**ViewController 1.h**

```
#import "SRWebSocket.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, SRWebSocketDelegate> 
@property (nonatomic,strong) SRWebSocket *socket;

-(void)sendMessageToServerWithContent:(NSString *)message;
```

**ViewController 1.m**

```
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

    socket.delegate = nil;
    socket = nil;

    socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverIP_GLOBAL]]];

    socket.delegate = self;

}

-(void)sendMessageToServerWithContent:(NSString *)message{

//irrelevant code for question removed
[self.socket send:jsonString];

}
```

**ViewController 2.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@property (nonatomic,strong) ViewController *viewVC;
@interface ContactsTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

**ViewController 2.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    viewVC = [ViewController alloc];

    [viewVC sendMessageToServerWithContent:@"Test"]; 
    //When calling from here, the socket object in ViewController 1 is nil

}
```

Comment: When the `socket` property is initialized? Try to check what happens first, `socket` initialization or `ViewController 2` `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverIP_GLOBAL]]]; This happens in ViewController 1 before opening the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't initialize the object like:    `viewVC = [ViewController alloc];`

You have to pass the object of ViewContoller1 to ViewContoller2 i.e.

When you are pushing the ViewContoller2 on viewcontoller1 you have write storyboard deletgate code

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        ViewController2 *view2=[segue destinationViewController];
        view2.viewVC=self; // pass viewcontoller1 object to viewcontoller2
    }
```

And In ViewContoller2 You will access the viewContoller1 object in viewVC variable and you can directly call it like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [viewVC sendMessageToServerWithContent:@"Test"]; 
    //When calling from here, the socket object in ViewController 1 is nil

}
```

Comment: Thank you, also my VC1 was not inside a storyboard including it into a storyboard and using your answer it worked.

Comment: thanks IR Works Looking forward your vote on my post.

Comment: As Girijesh says, calling alloc on an object but not init is invalid (voted). Creating an object in Objective-C is **always** a 2-step process: alloc, then an init method. If you don't call init, it's an error. Always.

Answer (score 3):

You call `viewVC`, which even is not properly created and initialized. That's **not** the previous view controller the screen before.

1.To call the object's method, it should be properly initialized first.

```
viewVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

You said, the `socket` property initialized in `viewDidLoad` method. To force load the view, use the `loadView` method, if you haven't an intention to present the view first.

2.Don't initialize another `ViewController` if you want to use the certain object. In your case it should be controller from which the second controller presented.

Somewhere in ViewController.m file, when the second view controller is about to present:

```
ViewController2 *second=[[ViewController2 alloc] init];
second.vc1 = self; // now the second controller has a pointer to original object
[self presentViewController:second ...];
```

For `segue`-navigation

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryBoardSegue *)segue
{
  ViewController2 *second=(ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
  send.vc1 = self;
}
```

Now in `ViewController 2` `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.vc1 sendMessageToServerWithContent:@"Test"]; 
  }
```

**UPD**

Why don't you keep your socket in a separate [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object? That's much more simpler to use. It would be like:

```
[[MySpecialSocketManager sharedInstance] sendMessageToServerWithContent:@"Hello, Server!"];
```

See, how to implement singleton [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)